# How to get the id of the current view in dojo mobile?

Tags: dojo

I would like to know if there is a way to get the id of the current view in dojo mobile ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have handle on one of the view, visible or not you can do:

```
var visibleView = anyViewSibling.getShowingView();
```

If you do not have handle on one of the view you should be able to get one by id:

```
var anyViewSibling = dijitRegisty.byId("theIdOfOneOfTheViewSibling");
```